# How do I force an Image to the second Page VB

Tags: vb.net, printing

we are building postcards and I need the image to be on the second page, so the printer will do duplex printing and we'll have image on one side and text on the other

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class trial : Inherits Printing.PrintDocument
    Dim text As String
    Dim font As Font
    Dim leftText As String
    Dim pic As Image
    Dim paper As PaperSize
    Dim printNewPage As Boolean = True
    Dim page1 As Boolean = True

    Sub New(ByVal lefty As String, ByVal nam As String, ByVal add As String, ByVal cit As String, ByVal zi As String, ByVal pi As Image, ByVal ps As PaperSize)
        font = New Font("Arial", 12)
        text = nam & Environment.NewLine & add & Environment.NewLine & cit & ", IN" & Environment.NewLine & zi
        paper = ps
        leftText = lefty
        pic = pi
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub onPrintPage(ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

        MyBase.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paper
        If page1 Then
            printLeft(e)
            printright(e)
        End If
        If printNewPage Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            printFront(e)
        Else
            e.HasMorePages = False
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub printLeft(ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        Dim area As RectangleF = New RectangleF(20, 20, 150, 400)
        Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(leftText, font, Brushes.Black, area, format)

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 200, 20, 200, 399)

    End Sub

    Private Sub printright(ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

        Dim area As RectangleF = New RectangleF(200, 20, 200, 400)
        Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, area, format)

        page1 = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub printFront(ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

        Dim area As RectangleF = New RectangleF(20, 500, 400, 400)

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pic, area)

        printNewPage = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: And your question is? Answers on a postcard...

Comment: How do I force the picture to page two of the print

Answer (score 0):

If the printer is set to do duplex printing by default then duplex printing will occur automatically if you print a document that is more than one page. You need to have a look at the [PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages.aspx) property. You need to set this to True after printing the first page.